# How to execute mysql scripts in cloudfoundry

Tags: mysql, grails-2.0, cloud-foundry

I have a .sql file (initial sql scripts). I have recently deployed application in cloudfoundry, So I want to run these scripts to make application work, Scripts will update more than 5 db tables.

Is there any other way to run the mysql scripts from the grails application on start up Or Is there any provision to run the scripts in the cloudfoundry.

Answer (score 1):

you have several options here.

- The first one (which I recommend), is to use something like http://liquibase.org/ (there is a Grails plugin for it: http://grails.org/plugin/liquibase). This tool will make sure that any script you give it will run prior to the app starting, without running the same script twice, etc. This is great to keep track of your database changes.
  This works independently of CloudFoundry and would help anyone installing your app having an up to date schema
- The second option would be to tunnel to the CloudFoundry database and run the script to the db. Have a look at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html or even easier with STS : http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/07/31/cloud-foundry-integration-for-eclipse-now-supports-tunneling-to-services/

Answer (score 0):

Yup, what ebottard said! :-) Although, personally I would opt for using the tunnel feature on VMC, but that said, I am a Ruby guy!

Be weary of the fact that there are timeouts against queries in MySQL if are bootstrapping your database with large datasets!