# Cloudfoundry relation "user" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, cloud-foundry, relation

I'm currently trying to deploy my application in cloudfoundry. My web is built on spring+postgre+hibernate. The problem I'm having is whenever I try to access the database, I'm having an error relation "user" does not exist.

I am sure that it is properly connecting to a postgres database. But my problem is that , it seems like it is not connecting to my local database but instead to somewhere else that's why it can't access the user table I defined.

I've tried to execute some query like "select * from pg_tables", and it executes well but the result is not the same with my local database. I've also seen that the table owner is vcap. I wonder why I'm having this error and how I could solve it.

I've been trying to fix these a couple of days. But to no avail that's why I've already posted here.

I hope someone could help me here.

I'll appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify: When you deploy on CloudFoundry and bind to a Postgres service, you get a fresh blank db managed for you by CF. So it is normal that it runs under a different user, and you should not even care about that. The interesting point though, is that the db is blank. So you should have some mechanism to populate it, if not to at least create the tables etc, you need. You can refer to this question where I suggested some technical solutions for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431272/how-to-execute-mysql-scripts-in-cloudfoundry/12435583#12435583

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Now atleast I understand what is happening! so that it means, I cannot use my existing posgres database in my local machine? Actually I can create the tables with hibernate. However, how about the data's in my table, I think I cannot populate them.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, you have several solutions here. Either use something like Liquibase, especially if you want to do incremental development and/or work with other people, OR use the tunneling feature and populate it in one-shot. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-on to ebottard's comment suggestion that addresses [provisioning a service](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/services.html), 
a way to prepopulate the database is to use a tunnel which connects your postgres client to the cloudfoundry postgres database, as described in [Tunneling to a Cloudfoundry Service](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html#prerequisites).